# How to know which handle is getting used in jquery resizable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

i am using jquery resizable to resize a div

```
$("#mainDiv").resizable({
        handles: 's, e',
        start: function(event, ui) { 
        // want to perform some action here
    },
        resize: function(event, ui) { 
        // want to perform some action here }
    });
```

now i want to do some stuff based on fact that whether `s` or `e` is selected to resize basically resizing is vertical or horizontal how to do that

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The axis is placed as data on your element under `ui-resizable` like this:

`$(element).data('ui-resizable').axis`

Comment: What does your `element` refer to?

Comment: function (event, ui) {                var axis = $(ui.element).data("resizable").axis; }

Comment: a little fix to the last comment - function (event, ui) { var axis = $(ui.element).data("ui-resizable").axis; }

Answer (score 3):

```
// the following will return direction as "n", "e", "s", "se" etc.
$("#selector").resizable({
    resize: function(e, ui) {
        // for jquery-ui 1.9.2
        var direction = $(this).data('resizable').axis;
        // for jquery-ui 1.11.4
        var direction = $(this).data('ui-resizable').axis;
    }
});
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'axis' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Could you implement a function for the stop event and then check whether the element has been resized horizontally or vertically using ui.originalSize and ui.size, something like:

```
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.originalSize.width !== ui.size.width) {
            //element has been resized horizontally
        }
        if (ui.originalSize.height !== ui.size.height) {
            //element has been resized vertically
        }
    }
```

Comment: no this will not server my purpose then, need to do at start and while resizing

Comment: you could use this code in a function for the resize event which would determine which handle was dragged, not sure how you can achieve this on start before any resize has taken place..

Answer (score 0):

Done changed

```
ui: function() {
    return {
        originalElement: this.originalElement,
        element: this.element,
        helper: this.helper,
        position: this.position,
        size: this.size,
        originalSize: this.originalSize,
        originalPosition: this.originalPosition,
        };
}
```

to

```
ui: function() {
    return {
        originalElement: this.originalElement,
        element: this.element,
        helper: this.helper,
        position: this.position,
        size: this.size,
        originalSize: this.originalSize,
        originalPosition: this.originalPosition,
        handle : this.axis
    };
}
```

ui.handle returns me handle name :)

Answer (score 0):

I used this method from:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13832254/1896534

```
 var handleTarget; //set scope

    $('#resize-this').resizable({
      handles: 'n,e,s,w',

      start: function(ui,event){
        handleTarget = $(event.originalEvent.target);
      },

      resize: function(ui,event){
        if (handleTarget.hasClass('ui-resizable-s'){
           //do stuff
        }
      } 
    )};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on the answer by @user3322509:

```
$("#selector").resizable({      
    resize: function(e,ui) {
        console.log( ui.element.data("ui-resizable").axis )
    }
});
```