# jQuery's resizable plugin: Which handle is used?

Tags: jquery

Could you please tell me how to know which of the handles (n, e, s, or w) is used to resized an element?

Comment: Do you want this information during a `resize` event callback, or do you want to be able to specify these as configuration options? What bigger task are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4):

topic is old but I was looking for the same answer and found this method.

```
    var handleTarget; //set scope

    $('#resize-this').resizable({
      handles: 'n,e,s,w',

      start: function(ui,event){
        handleTarget = $(event.originalEvent.target);
      },

      resize: function(ui,event){
        if (handleTarget.hasClass('ui-resizable-s'){
           //do stuff
        }
      } 
    )};
```

Answer (score 0):

**handles**
`String, Object    Default:'e, s, se'`

> If specified as a string, should be a comma-split list of any of the
>   following: 'n, e, s, w, ne, se, sw, nw, all'. The necessary handles
>   will be auto-generated by the plugin.
>
> If specified as an object, the following keys are supported: { n, e,
>   s, w, ne, se, sw, nw }. The value of any specified should be a jQuery
>   selector matching the child element of the resizable to use as that
>   handle. If the handle is not a child of the resizable, you can pass in
>   the DOMElement or a valid jQuery object directly.

*Code examples*

Initialize a resizable with the handles option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).resizable({ handles: 'n, e, s, w' });
```

Get or set the handles option, after init.

```
//getter
var handles = $( ".selector" ).resizable( "option", "handles" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).resizable( "option", "handles", 'n, e, s, w' );
```

[source](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#option-handles)

Comment: Why exactly was this downvoted ? Isn't it a correct answer to the question ?