# jQuery UI - resizable. Check direction

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to ask how to check direction of resizable element in jQuery UI - resizable. I know I can check it horizontally:

```
$(this).data(ui-resizable).axis
```

I would like to know that I resize it to left or to right.

Comment: Please see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20833716/776687

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems theres no event to deal with that. I set up a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wxrm7w23/

```
window.resizeWidth = 0;
$(function () {
    $("#resizable").resizable({
        containment: "#container",
        resize: function (event, ui) {
            var currentWidth = ui.size.width;
            var direction = (currentWidth > window.resizeWidth) ? 'right' : 'left';
            window.resizeWidth = ui.size.width;
            $('.d #direction').text(direction);
        }
    });
});
```

The "magic" is pretty easy. I check the width twice inside the resize event and save it to a global var. So you have both numbers to compare with: the current width of the box and the width before the next resize event.