# jQuery resizable - how to check direction on start event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I initialize resizable DIV as

```
$('#someDiv').resizable({
    handles: "n, e, s, w",
    start: function(event, ui) {
        //    figure out the resize direction here...
    }
});
```

How I can know the direction at the start of a resize operation?

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pshenichnov/gwztt6ur/)

Comment: By "direction" do you mean the way it is being dragged?

Comment: yes... for example if I drag west border I want to know that it is "west" inside "start" event handler.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21839287/2456258

Answer (score -2, accepted):

JS:

```
$('#someDiv').resizable({
    handles: "n, e, s, w",
    start: function (event, ui) {
        //    figure out the resize direction here...
        console.log(event);
        var srcEl = event.originalEvent.srcElement.className;
        console.log(srcEl);
        var direction = srcEl.replace('ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-', '');
        console.log(srcEl, direction);
        console.log('You are manipulating', direction);
    }
});
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/gwztt6ur/1/

Comment: @SterlingArcher it logs through every step of the code?!

Comment: You can argue, or you could write a simple explanation and I'll revert. Now matter how trivial you think the answer is, it's obviously not for the OP.

Comment: @SterlingArcher The OP has accepted the answer and it's served it's purpose as far as I am concerned.  There's nothing wrong with me encouraging the reader to `read-around` the topic, no-matter what sanctimonious voting you partake in, you are free to judge and answer on your own account.

Comment: Downvoting, this answer isn't helpful for anything other than copypaste coding.